# How can i create and use only SOAP server without client on GAE?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

First, sorry for my poor English.
I found this article and follow it.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap?hl=vi

It's worked. Now i want to create only the server like that to use in other client.Is that ok?
For example when i deployed the HelloSOAPServerServlet  to the abc@appspot.com 
And when i want to use my service, i just paste this URL:  abc@appspot.com/hellosoapserver?name=SOAP&arriving=true  to the browser. How can i do something like that?
Because i want my client what use this service is the Andoird phone.

Answer (score 0):

`abc@appspot.com` is an email address. You can not deploy GAE code to it.

When you create a [GAE application](https://appengine.google.com) you must pick a unique application name, for example `mysoap`. The url of your app would then be `http://mysoap.appspot.com/`.

After you [upload your code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading) to it you could access your SOAP at `http://mysoap.appspot.com/hellosoapserver?name=SOAP&arriving=true`

Answer (score 0):

You got it in that example.

You made the SOAP Webservice in :

**Building a SOAP Server on Google App Engine**

and then you created a client that consume it from a Servlet:

**Building a SOAP Client on Google App Engine Using JAX-WS**

Now what you need is to make a HTTP Client call to that URL from your Android application with correct values in params.

Using the example available at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html and url provided your sample

```
   URL url = new URL(" http://greeter-client.appspot.com/hellosoapclient?name=SOAP&arriving=true");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

In **readStream** is where you read the response from your service hosted at GAE

readStream can be something like this:

```
private static String readStream(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```